# Are Exponential and Trigonometric Functions the Only Non-Trivial Solutions to $F'(x)=F(x+a)$?

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, functional-equations

> Are exponential & trigonometric functions the only non-trivial solutions to $F'(x)=F(x+a)$?

$F(x)=0$ would be the trivial solution. Then, for $a=0$ (or  $a=2\pi i$), we have $F(x)=e^x$, and for $a=\dfrac\pi2$ there are $F(x)=\sin x$ and $F(x)=\cos x$. But the three are connected by [*Euler's formula*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) $e^{ix}=\cos x$ $+i\sin x$. Indeed, on a more [general](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_differential_equation#The_characteristic_equation) note, letting $F(x)=e^{\lambda x}$, we have $\lambda=\dfrac{W(-a)}{-a}$ where *W* is the [*Lambert W function*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). My question would be if these are the *only* ones, due to the *special* properties of the number *e* and the *exponential function*, or if there aren't by any chance *more*, which do *not* belong in the same family or category as these, i.e., which are not *exponential* or *trigonometric* in nature ? Thank you.

Comment: That seems like an unrealistic expectation.  Delay differential equations have an entire interval of definition as input.  So you could easily ensure that's not an exponential or trig function.

Comment: For example, if $a<0$ is real, look at the solutions with $F(x)=0$ on $[0,-a)$.  That's not trig or exponential, unless its the zero function.

Comment: Possibly the question becomes more interesting (or tractable) if $F$ is assumed analytic? If $F$ is merely $C^\infty$, then taking for example $a = 1$ and any $C^\infty$ function $F$ such that $F^{(n)}(0) = 0 = F^{(n)}(1)$ for all $n \geq 0$, the extension of $F$ to any interval $[n-1, n]$, for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, can be defined recursively by appealing to the functional equation.

Comment: Questions on this kind of equation are a recurrent theme on this site. It is an example of a linear retarded differential equation (up to a change of sign). There is a survey "A shifted view of fundamental physics" by Atiyah and Moore, available on arXiv 1009 2176.

Comment: From a more purely mathematical perspective, I was also able to find [this](http://www.emis.de/journals/EJDE/conf-proc/13/i2/iakovleva.pdf).

Comment: related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/199691/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at these MO entries:
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/114875/on-equation-fz1-fz-fz/114878#114878 ,
and 
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/156312/solve-fx-int-x-1x1-ft-mathrmdt/156315#156315 .
They contain the answer to your question.

EDIT. To put it shortly, the answer is: "yes" and "no".
In exactly the same sense as the answer to a simpler question: 
"Is every periodic function an
exponential/trigonometric sum"? "Yes" for a physicist, and "no" for a mathematician.
But every periodic function is a limit of exp/trig sums.

Comment: So you're saying that exponential and trigonometric functions are indeed the *only* type of solutions to this problem, or am I misunderstanding something ?

Comment: It depends on the exact definition of "trig and exp functions". You can take limits of their linear combinations.  With a proper definition of limits all solutions are such limits. The references are given in MO entries that I cited.

Comment: I guess it's a good thing that I nagged my father into teaching me the [Cyrillic alphabet](http://en.knigoteka.net/math/file5915.html) when I was a kid. :-) I found the *Gelfond* reference on page $379-380$.

Comment: Also in [RAND](http://www.rand.org/content/dam/rand/pubs/reports/2006/R374.pdf), on page $45$.

Comment: Gelfond is available in English MR0342890. But in Russian it is available FREE. As most Russian math books are. A good justification to learn Cyrillic alphabet:-)

Comment: However I emphasize that Hormander's book covers all of this subject and much more. It is difficult to read, but rewarding.