# Functional Equation involving derivatives and time-steps

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, exponential-function, functional-equations, transcendental-equations

I am attempting to solve the equation

$$f(x + 1) = f'(x)$$

for distributions $C \rightarrow C: f(x)$

My first guess to exploit the fact that this seems similar to identity

$$\sin\left( \frac{\pi}{2} - x\right) = \cos(x) = \frac{d}{dx} [\sin(x)] $$

I therefore assume my answer takes on the form:

$$Ce^{ax}$$

And now attempt to solve:

$$Ce^{a(x+1)} = Cae^{ax}$$

Yielding

$$e^{a}e^{ax} = ae^{ax}$$

Yielding

$$e^a = a$$

How do I extract a single solution, let alone the infinitely many complex solutions for $a$ that satisfy this equation?

Comment: I think $e^a=a$ has only one (if any) real solution $a_0$. When $a$ is complex you can proove that $a=a_0+ib$ with real $b$. Then you can solve another equantion for $b$ (which involve $in b$, I think)

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/199691/find-f-where-fx-f1x) is exactly the same problem.

Comment: A [related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/815687) question.