# Is there a non-constant function $f$ such that $f'(x) = f(x - 1)$?

Tags: calculus, fibonacci-numbers, discrete-calculus

In discrete calculus, where the difference operator $\Delta f = f(x + 1) - f(x)$ takes the place of $\frac{d}{dx}$, Fibonacci sequences are given by the functions satisfying:

$$
\Delta f(x) = f(x - 1)
$$

Is there a non-constant function such that $\frac{d}{dx}f(x) = f(x - 1)$? If it exists, it would be the "continuous analogue of the Fibonacci sequence" in this sense, which seems cool.

Comment: Well, the smartalec answer would be that $f(x) = 0$ works, but I presume you meant non-zero $f$.

Comment: A [related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/815687) question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Choose constant $C$ that satisfies $C=e^{-C}$.  Note that $C=W(1)\approx 0.567$.  We take

$$f(x)=e^{Cx}$$
$$f'(x)=Ce^{Cx}$$
$$f(x-1)=e^{C(x-1)}=e^{Cx}e^{-C}=Ce^{Cx}$$

Comment: Wow, wouldn't have thought of that. What is the function $W$ -- is that the Lambert W function?

Comment: Too bad this function doesn't agree with Fibonacci sequence for $x\in\mathbb{N}$. Would be great if that had happen.

Comment: @elirose This isn't very surprising given that Fibonacci's solutions are also exponential.

Comment: Yes, it's the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).  In fact this particular $C$ has a name, it's the [Omega constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omega_constant).