# Functional equation with integral: $ f(x) = \int_0^x f(s) \, \mathrm ds $

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, functional-equations

I was hoping for some help with this integral relation. I would prefer hints to answers. I'm trying to find any solution to this relation:

$$ f(x) = \int_0^x f(s) \, \mathrm ds $$

I feel like it should be some variation of the exponential function that is $0$ for $x \le 0$, but I'm not sure.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try taking the derivative of both sides and remember FToC. You're going to be sad to know that the only analytic solution is $y = 0$.

Comment: @kaynex how is that the only solution? the fundamental theorem of calculus yields $$\frac{df}{dx} = f(x)$$

Comment: That's what I arrived at, leading me to believe that $e^x$ is a solution, but plugging into integral does not confirm that. I get $e^x = e^x - 1$. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Hint: substitute $x=0$ to get $f(0) = 0$.

Comment: @mlc cheers for that.

Comment: So the function can't change since the initial rate of change is 0 is the intuition I guess. @Kaynex I am sad indeed.

Comment: A [related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/815687) question.

Comment: What hypothesis do you have on $f$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the derivative of both sides

$$\frac{d}{dx}f(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\int_{0}^{x}f(s)\space ds$$

Note that $\int_{0}^{x} f(s) ds=F(x)-F(0)$. The derivative of $F(x)$ is $f(x)$ and the derivative of $F(0)=0$. Hence

$$f'(x)=f(x)$$

There are two possiblities.

Once is $f(x)=0$, another is $f(x)=ce^x$

But if we substitute $f(x)=ce^x$ into the first equation the left hand side is

$$\frac{d}{dx}ce^x=ce^x$$

And the right hand side is

$$\int_{0}^{x}ce^s\space ds=ce^x-c$$

If set both side to equal eachother we get

$$0=-c$$

Hence $f(x)=0$ is the only solution.

Comment: I think the procedure is fine but you need to make some assumption on $f$