# What functions have the property that $\frac{d}{dx}f(x) = c \cdot f(x+1)$?

Tags: derivatives, intuition, transformation

If we are allowed to pick any real-valued constant $c$ that helps, when does

$$\frac{d}{dx}f(x) = c \cdot f(x+1)$$

In other words, when does the derivative of a function $f(x)$ equal some constant times $f(x)$?

**EXAMPLE**

If we set $f(x) = \sin{ (\frac{\pi}{2}x) }$, then

$$\frac{d}{dx} \left( \sin (\frac{\pi}{2}x)  \right) = \frac{\pi}{2}\sin (\frac{\pi}{2}(x+1)) $$

This also works for $f(x) = \cos (\frac{\pi}{2}x) $:

$$\frac{d}{dx} \left( \cos (\frac{\pi}{2}x)  \right) =\frac{\pi}{2} \cos (\frac{\pi}{2}(x+1)) $$

**WHAT I'M AFTER**

Is there some way of finding formulas that possess this property?

Perhaps there is a way to formalize a method.  I'd like to know if there's an easy way to find formulas that work.

Comment: How did you calculate this derivative? Maybe I'm just missing an obvious trigonometric identity, but I got something completely different, which wolfframalpha verifies here: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdx+sin+%28x*pi%2F2%29

Comment: @AlfredYerger, I believe he is using $\sin (t + (\pi/2)) =  \cos t$

Comment: By letting $f(x) = g(cx)$ your problem is equivalent to finding a $g(x)$ such that $g'(x) = g(x+c)$. A natural response would be to put in the Fourier series and find the constraint on the coefficients.

Answer (score 6):

The infinitesimal generator corresponding to the translation operator is differentiation:

$$ e^{t \frac{d}{dx}} f(x) = f(x+t). $$

That is, if we write $D = d/dx$ then

$$ D f = c e^{D} f. $$

So at least formally, $f$ is an eigenfunction of the operator $ D - ce^{D} $ corresponding to the eigenvalue $0$.

Instead, we begin by making an *ansatz*. That is, let us try $f = e^{kx}$. Then what we want to solve is now the following equation.

$$ 0 = (D - ce^{D})e^{kx} = (k - ce^{k}) e^{kx} \quad \Longrightarrow \quad k - ce^{k} = 0. $$

This equation can be solved using the [*Lambert W-function*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), and any complex solution to this equation leads to a solution to our original equation. This is the very approach that Will Jagy adopted.

**Edited.** I should correct my answer in that functional analysis does not seem to provide enough power to analyze the solution. Sorry about this confusion.

Comment: I want to know what functional analysis can be used. To me the ansatz approach is clear to me (almost obvious) and what I'd rather know is what are all possible solutions.

Comment: @WillJagy, I like your answer, makes sense that linear combinations of the multiple solutions to your equation work, but I'm not convinced those are the only solutions.

Comment: @nayrb, thanks, i erased my comment after reading your answer. I have no way of knowing whether all solutions come from a Fourier type series of these basic ones. Could be, but I do not believe such questions are ever all that easy.

Answer (score 5):

For fixed $c,$ if $a / e^a = c,$ then $e^{ax}$ works. Linear ODE, so you can add solutions with the same $c.$

Errands to run, look at it later. Possible benefit to allowing complex $a.$ Yes, try $a=i \pi / 2$ or similar. Right, next try $a=-i \pi / 2.$ You can add or subtract these, divide by $i$ if needed, no harm in constant multiple. I think sums of these give all; just a guess for now.

EEDDIITT: The holomorphic function $$g(z) = \frac{z}{e^z}$$ is far from injective. for example, $g(i \pi / 2) = \pi/2$ and $g(-i \pi / 2) = \pi/2.$ So, to get the original value of $c = \pi/2,$ we can take 
$$ A e^{i \pi x / 2} + B e^{-i \pi x / 2}  $$
with real or complex constants $A,B.$ As 
$$  e^{i \pi x / 2} = \cos \frac{\pi x}{2} + i \sin \frac{\pi x}{2},  $$ we can get your original examples as
$$ \left( e^{i \pi x / 2} +  e^{-i \pi x / 2} \right) / 2,  $$
then
$$ \left( e^{i \pi x / 2} -  e^{-i \pi x / 2} \right) / (2i).  $$

There should be a countably infinite set of solutions to
$$ \color{magenta}{ \frac{z}{e^z} = \frac{\pi}{2}},  $$
occurring in conjugate pairs. Information about these can be gathered from the [Lambert W Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), because
$$ \color{magenta}{ -z e^{-z} = -\frac{\pi}{2}},  $$
so we can take $v=-z$ and solve
$$ \color{magenta}{ v e^v = -\frac{\pi}{2}}.  $$
Compare the first example in [VALUES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Special_values). Evidently MATLAB allows you to demand the non-principal branches, one at a time. I suspect that if you actually own Mathematica you can evaluate ProductLog[1, -Pi/2] but it does not seem to cooperate on Alpha. Oh, well. Once i made a Newton's method thing for tyhe complex plane, maybe i can find the first non-principal (conjugate pair of) value myself, numerically at least. Matter of carefully finding an approximate location first...

EEDDIITT worked this time [ONE](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ProductLog%5B1,%20-Pi/2%5D&dataset=),
$$ v_1 =  -1.60429 \pm 7.64719 i ; \; \; \; z_1 =  1.60429091344801 \pm 7.64719227612459 i  $$ 
[TWO](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ProductLog%5B2,%20-Pi/2%5D&dataset=)
$$ v_2 =  -2.19834 \pm 13.981208 i ; \; \; \; z_2 = 2.1983426299819 \pm 13.981208306240 i    $$

Answer (score 3):

If we let $f\in \mathcal{C}^{\infty}$, then, we can use $f(x+1)$'s Taylor expansion around $1$ to get $$f'(x)=\sum_{k\ge 0}f^{(k)}(1)\frac{x^k}{k!}=\sum_{k\ge 0}f(k+1)\frac{(cx)^k}{k!}\\ \Rightarrow f(x)=\sum_{k\ge 0}f(k)\frac{(cx)^k}{k!}$$ So, for example taking $$f(k)=\left\{\begin{array}{rl}
0 & k\ \mbox{even}\\
(-1)^k& k\ \mbox{odd}
\end{array}
\right.$$ gives $f(x)=\sin(cx)$ similarly you'll get $f(x)=\cos(cx)$ by taking $$f(k)=\left\{\begin{array}{rl}
(-1)^k & k\ \mbox{even}\\
0& k\ \mbox{odd}
\end{array}
\right.$$ with $c=\pi/2$.

Comment: This seems more of an after the fact sort of thing, once you have found this solution. What Taylor series give us is an infinite system of an infinite number of variables that we need to solve.

Comment: That is true @nayrb. I was later thinking something else, but Will Jagy has given the same ideas (more or less) that I was thinking about :-)

Answer (score 2):

By way of an extended comment, consider the following. By putting $f(x)=g(cx)$ we can convert the equation to $c g'(cx) = c g(cx+c)$ or with $cx \to x$,
$$g'(x) = g(x+c).$$

See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/199691/find-f-where-fx-f1x) for how to find all solutions of $g'(x)=g(x+1)$, a very similar problem.

Here's a more convincing reason why Will Jagy's ansatz is probably the only solution.
Take the Fourier transform:
$$\mathcal{F}[g'(x)] = \mathcal{F}[g(x+c)]$$
implying
$$-2 \pi \xi i G(\xi) = e^{2 \pi i \xi c} G(\xi)$$
implying $G(\xi) = 0$ except for when $\xi = -e^{2 \pi i \xi c}/{2 \pi i}$. For one such solution $\xi = a$, then
$$G(\xi) =A \delta(\xi - a)$$
which goes back to
$$g(x) = A e^{2 \pi i a x}$$
as a solution. So $f(x) = g(cx) = A e^{2 \pi i c a x}$.