# how do I solve this differential equation $f(x+1)=f'(x)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

how do I solve this differential equation $f(x+1)=f'(x)$?

> Background:
> I have not taken any collage courses or any calculus courses yet, I'm still in high school. I know a lot of math because of videos from 3blue1brown and other, and I do practice problems I make up. Today I was trying to solve many differential equations some I couldn't do and some I was able to do like $h'(x)=h(x)x^2$. first I right $h(x)$ in terms of $e^{g(x)}$ when I take the derivative of it and I get $g'(x) e^{g(x)}=x^2 e^{g(x)}$ then I get $g(x)$ to be $\frac{x^3}{3}$ so $h(x)= e^{\frac{x^3}{3}}$. I know how to solve some differential equations.

I would like to learn a new technique to solve differential equations when the input changes. I would like to know the answer to this differential equation. But I also want to learn how to solve more types of differential equations. Any tips would help.

Comment: If you write down a random differential equation, almost certainly you will not be able to solve it.

Comment: @MichaelBarz good to know. Is this one possible?

Comment: I would be very surprised if it was.

Comment: Where did you find these problems? If they are from a book, then it's very likely that the techniques which are neccesary to solve them are somewhere in the pages before the problems.

Comment: Technically, that's not a differential equation. It's a differential-difference equation, also called a delay-differential equation, and the solution techniques are different, and generally not taught in the undergrad math curriculum.

Comment: Such equations come up in analytic number theory. See, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dickman_function

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz I tried to make up a seemingly simple problem, I don't have any math books at home, my family hates math.

Comment: Your family hates maths? See if you can test into a gifted program: if you want to discuss this further, please do so in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/199691/find-f-where-fx-f1x.

Comment: Notice that there are interesting solutions for $f(x+1)=Cf'(x)$ for some constant $C$, such as $f(x)=\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}x\right)$.