# delayed differential equation: $øf(øx) = 2f(x)∫f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t$, integrated over $[0,x]$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, delay-differential-equations

I would like to solve this differential equation that is similar to [the delayed differential equation here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61818/how-to-solve-differential-equations-of-the-form-fx-fx-a).

this is the DE: $f'(x) = f(kx), \;$
for some real $k$.

The reason for attempting this problem is that I am interested in solving this DE but do not have the means to solve it:

$øf(øx) = 2f(x)∫f(t)\mathrm{d}t$ integrated over $[0,x]$.

I though I'd start with a simpler yet similar problem to help me understand the original question.

Comment: Haven't you studied Laplace Transform ? It's the ideal tool for this kind of questions.

Comment: The title does not fit what you are asking !

Comment: I realize that delayed differential equations refers to equations involving f(t) and f(t+k) and their derivatives but I'm not sure what to call this sort of thing when it is scaled by a factor rather than shifted. Also, I don't see how laplace transforms would help, I did try that method but got this for the first equation:    s L{f(t)} - f(0) = L{f(kt)}      (L should be a scripted L but I cant type that)    I'm left with a problem I can't solve. Thanks for the power series solution @RobertIsrael, very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write formally  $f(x) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i x^i$, your equation
$f'(x) = f(kx)$ becomes 
$$ \sum_{i=0}^\infty ((i+1) a_{i+1} - k^i a_i) x^i$$
The solution to the recurrence $(i+1) a_{i+1} = k^i a_i$ is
$$ a_i = a_0 \frac{k^{i(i-1)/2}}{i!}$$
The series $$ \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{k^{i(i-1)/2}}{i!} x^i$$
converges to an entire function of $x$ for $|k| < 1$.