# Solutions for $y'(x)=y(x+a)$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-equations

The differential equation $y'(x)=y(x+a)$ does have solutions for $a=\frac\pi 2$ but what about other values of $a$? What about $a=1$?

Comment: See this extensive solution of mine : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4611530/particular-differential-equation/4611566#4611566

Comment: Did you try Laplace/Fourrier transform to solve it?