# Is there a non trivial function such that $\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x} = f(x+1)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Is there a non trivial function such that

$$\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x} = f(x+1)$$

I'm not sure if the uniqueness of the ODE apply here because $\partial_x e^x =e^x$. If the continuous case did not work, what about the discrete series?

Comment: If $f$ is a 1-variable function, then what is the point of using partial derivatives notation?

Comment: See this answer of mine : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4611530/particular-differential-equation/4611566#4611566

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve differential equations of the form $f'(x) = f(x + a)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61818/how-to-solve-differential-equations-of-the-form-fx-fx-a)

Comment: @Ryszard correct - you actually need $a=e^a$ which has complex solutions only

Comment: check the Wikipedia of [Delayed Differential Equations (DDEs)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_differential_equation#The_characteristic_equation)