# Differential equation with memory

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, delay-differential-equations

I am trying to integrate this equation:

$$
\frac{dz}{dt} = \alpha \cdot (s(t)-z(t-1))
$$

I came up with this equation to model a "leaky integrator" system where s(t) are some samples from the environment and z(t) is a "decision variable". Thus this system can continuously decide between 2 alternatives based on the sign of z(t).

However, I'm not sure how to integrate the equation and solve for z(t), mainly because of the term z(t-1) which Wolfram Alpha seems to struggle with... Any tips?

Comment: You might try solving it in steps of 1, following the approach here. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_differential_equation

Comment: This equation belongs to the family of *delayed differential equations*. You may be interested in this answer of mine : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4611530/particular-differential-equation/4611566#4611566

Comment: This is a [DDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_differential_equation). For the homogeneous solution, as with other DEs, you could reduce the equation to its characteristic equation via $z(t):=e^{\lambda t}$ (you don't get a polynomial) and you can then solve that for $\lambda$ via the [Lambert-W function](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/ProductLog2/). When solving for the particular solution you could use the [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Properties_and_theorems) and it's inverse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your differential equation is a delay differential equation (DDE). You can find a quick [overview](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_differential_equation) on this here.

##### Solving for the homogeneous solution

When solving a homogeneous solution of an linear DDE you could reduce it to it's characteristic equation using the substitution $z\left( t \right) := e^{\lambda \cdot t} \implies z^{\left( n \right)}\left( t + \tau \right) \equiv \lambda^{n} \cdot e^{\lambda \cdot \left( t + \tau \right)}$. You will get no polynomial like in ODEs but a similar equation wich you can solve using the [Lambert-W Function](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/ProductLog2/) $\operatorname{W}_{k}$:

\begin{align*}
\frac{\operatorname{d}z\left( t \right)}{\operatorname{d}t} &= \alpha \cdot \left( s\left( t \right) - z\left( t - 1 \right) \right)\\
\frac{\operatorname{d}z_{h}\left( t \right)}{\operatorname{d}t} &= -\alpha \cdot z_{h}\left( t - 1 \right) \tag{$z_{h}\left( t \right) := e^{\lambda \cdot t}$}\\
\lambda \cdot e^{\lambda \cdot t} &= -\alpha \cdot e^{\lambda \cdot \left( t - 1 \right)}\\
\lambda \cdot e^{\lambda \cdot t} &= -\alpha \cdot e^{\lambda \cdot t} \cdot e^{-\lambda} \tag{$\div e^{\lambda \cdot t}$}\\
\lambda &= -\alpha \cdot e^{-\lambda} \tag{$\cdot e^{\lambda}$}\\
\lambda \cdot e^{\lambda} &= -\alpha \tag{$\operatorname{W}_{k}\left( \cdot \right)$}\\
\lambda &= \operatorname{W}_{k}\left( -\alpha \right)\\
\end{align*}
where $k$ is any integer ($k \in \mathbb{Z}$).

So
$$\fbox{$
\begin{align*}
z_{h}\left( t \right) &= \text{c} \cdot e^{\operatorname{W}_{k}\left( -\alpha \right) \cdot t}\\
\end{align*}
$}$$
or
$$\fbox{$
\begin{align*}
z_{h}\left( t \right) &= \sum\limits_{k = -\infty}^{\infty}\left[ \text{c}_{k} \cdot e^{\operatorname{W}_{k}\left( -\alpha \right) \cdot t} \right]\\
\end{align*}
$}$$
where $\left\{ \text{c},\, \text{c}_{k} \right\} \in \mathbb{C}$ are arbitrary complex constants.

##### Solving for particular solution

You can use the [Laplace transform $\mathcal{L}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform) and its inverse to find the particular solution here. The special [properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Properties_and_theorems) (here *Frequency-domain derivative* (I'll shorten it with Fdd) and *Frequency shifting* (I'll shorten it with Fs) allow for simple simplifications. Let's say $\tilde{z}$ is the inverse Laplace transform of $z$ the we could solve:

\begin{align*}
\frac{\operatorname{d}z\left( t \right)}{\operatorname{d}t} &= \alpha \cdot \left( s\left( t \right) - z\left( t - 1 \right) \right)\\
\frac{\operatorname{d}z\left( t \right)}{\operatorname{d}t} &= \alpha \cdot s\left( t \right) - \alpha \cdot z\left( t - 1 \right) \tag{$\cdot \left( -1 \right)$}\\
-\frac{\operatorname{d}z\left( t \right)}{\operatorname{d}t} &= \alpha \cdot z\left( t - 1 \right) - \alpha \cdot s\left( t \right) \tag{$\mathcal{L}_{t}^{-1}\left[ \cdot \right]\left\{ x \right\}$}\\
\mathcal{L}_{t}^{-1}\left[ -\frac{\operatorname{d}z\left( t \right)}{\operatorname{d}t} \right]\left\{ x \right\} &= \mathcal{L}_{t}^{-1}\left[ \alpha \cdot z\left( t - 1 \right) - \alpha \cdot s\left( t \right) \right]\left\{ x \right\} \tag{Fdd}\\
x \cdot \tilde{z}\left( x \right) &= \mathcal{L}_{t}^{-1}\left[ \alpha \cdot z\left( t - 1 \right) - \alpha \cdot s\left( t \right) \right]\left\{ x \right\} \tag{linearity}\\
x \cdot \tilde{z}\left( x \right) &= \alpha \cdot \mathcal{L}_{t}^{-1}\left[ x\left( t - 1 \right) \right]\left\{ x \right\} - \alpha \cdot \mathcal{L}_{t}^{-1}\left[ s\left( t \right) \right]\left\{ x \right\} \tag{Fs}\\
x \cdot \tilde{z}\left( x \right) &= \alpha \cdot e^{x} \cdot \tilde{z}\left( x \right) - \alpha \cdot \mathcal{L}_{t}^{-1}\left[ s\left( t \right) \right]\left\{ x \right\}\\
\end{align*}

Now we got a linear equation, which can be easily solved:

\begin{align*}
x \cdot \tilde{z}\left( x \right) &= \alpha \cdot e^{x} \cdot \tilde{z}\left( x \right) - \alpha \cdot \mathcal{L}_{t}^{-1}\left[ s\left( x \right) \right]\left\{ x \right\} \tag{$-\left( \alpha \cdot e^{x} \cdot \tilde{z}\left( x \right) \right)$}\\
\left( x - \alpha \cdot e^{x} \right) \cdot \tilde{z}\left( x \right) &= -\alpha \cdot \mathcal{L}_{t}^{-1}\left[ s\left( t \right) \right]\left\{ x \right\} \tag{$\cdot \left( -1 \right)$}\\
\left( \alpha \cdot e^{x} - x \right) \cdot \tilde{z}\left( x \right) &= \alpha \cdot \mathcal{L}_{t}^{-1}\left[ s\left( t \right) \right]\left\{ x \right\} \tag{$\div \left( \alpha \cdot e^{x} - x \right)$}\\
\tilde{z}\left( x \right) &= \frac{\alpha \cdot \mathcal{L}_{t}^{-1}\left[ s\left( t \right) \right]\left\{ x \right\}}{\alpha \cdot e^{x} - x} \tag{$\mathcal{L}_{x}\left[ \cdot \right]\left\{ t \right\}$}\\
z\left( t \right) &= \mathcal{L}_{x}\left[ \frac{\alpha \cdot \mathcal{L}_{t}^{-1}\left[ s\left( t \right) \right]\left\{ x \right\}}{\alpha \cdot e^{x} - x} \right]\left\{ t \right\}\\
\end{align*}

We get:
$$\fbox{$
\begin{align*}
z_{p}\left( t \right) &= \mathcal{L}_{x}\left[ \frac{\alpha \cdot \mathcal{L}_{t}^{-1}\left[ s\left( t \right) \right]\left\{ x \right\}}{\alpha \cdot e^{x} - x} \right]\left\{ t \right\}\\
\end{align*}
$}$$

This is the particular solution.

Note that you could also use at first the Laplace transform and then it's inverse. You would get a solution like [*Robert Israel*](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/8508/robert-israel).

##### "The" solution

We know $z\left( t \right) = z_{p}\left( t \right) + z_{h}\left( t \right)$, so we would get:
$$\fbox{$\fbox{$
\begin{align*}
z\left( t \right) &= \mathcal{L}_{x}\left[ \frac{\alpha \cdot \mathcal{L}_{t}^{-1}\left[ s\left( t \right) \right]\left\{ x \right\}}{\alpha \cdot e^{x} - x} \right]\left\{ t \right\} + \sum\limits_{k = -\infty}^{\infty}\left[ \text{c}_{k} \cdot e^{\operatorname{W}_{k}\left( -\alpha \right) \cdot t} \right]\\
\end{align*}
$}$}$$

Answer (score 1):

This is known as a delay-differential equation.
Note that for an "initial condition", you want to specify $z(t)$ on an interval of length $1$, say $(-1,0)$, rather than at just one point.

One way to try solving it is
with Laplace transform.  Since you're using $s$ in your equation, let me use
$u$ as the Laplace transform variable.  Then, with $Z(u)$ and $S(u)$ the Laplace transforms of $z$ and $s$, the Laplace transform of your equation is

$$u Z(u) - z(0) = \alpha S(u) - \alpha \int_{-1}^0 z(t) e^{-u(t+1)} \; dt - e^{-u} Z(u)$$

so

$$Z(u) = (u + e^{-u})^{-1} \left(z(0) + \alpha S(u) - \alpha \int_{-1}^0 z(t) e^{-u(t+1)}\; dt \right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that $S(t) = \sum_{k=0}^{n_s}a_k t^k$ and $z(t)= \sum_{k=0}^{n_z}b_k t^k$ this last for $t\in [-1,0]$,  after the Laplace transform we have

$$
s\hat z(s)-\alpha \hat S(s)+\alpha e^{-s}\hat z(s) -\int_{-1}^0z(t)e^{-s(t+1)}dt = z_0
$$

Regarding $\int_{-1}^0z(t)e^{-s(t+1)}dt$ we know that $\int_{-1}^0t^k e^{-s(t+1)}dt = T_k(s)$ which obeys the recurrence

$$
T_{k+1}(s)-\frac ks T_k(s) = \frac{(-1)^k}{s},\ \ \ \ T_0(s) = \frac{1-e^{-s}}{s}
$$

so we can write

$$
\hat z(s) = \frac{z_0+\alpha \hat S(s)+T(s)}{s+\alpha e^{-s}}=\frac{z_0+\alpha \hat S(s)+T(s)}{s(1+\frac{\alpha e^{-s}}{s})}
$$

with $T(s) = \sum b_k T_k(s)$ and now assuming $\|\frac{\alpha e^{-s}}{s}\| < 1$ we have

$$
\frac{1}{1+\frac{\alpha e^{-s}}{s}}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k\left(\frac{\alpha e^{-s}}{s}\right)^k
$$

making $\hat z(s)$ invertible.